# Enable PHP-ZTS and MPM Workers in Apache to lower memory footprint, but still keep MySQL?

Tags: apache-2.2, mysql, php5, memory-usage, mpm-worker

My question is quite similar to [this one](https://serverfault.com/questions/21106/how-to-reduce-memory-usage-on-a-unix-webserver) in that I'm trying to reduce the memory footprint of my website on a somewhat meager shared hosting solution.  I'm going to be playing around with my own Apache settings like he did, but I'd also like to try getting PHP-ZTS and MPM Workers functioning rather than using Prefork.

The problem is, when I enable Workers, all I get is a blank white page instead of my Wordpress homepage. A phpinfo() page shows that PHP is functioning correctly, but that MySQL isn't.  My server is Fedora 12.

Does anyone have any experience with getting Workers, php-zts, and MySQL functioning together properly?  Any help appreciated.  I will be diligent in upvoting and providing follow-up info.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note the last recommendation in the question you linked! Use [nginx](http://nginx.org/en/download.html) and [PHP-CGI](http://wiki.nginx.org/PHPFcgiExample) for a low-memory web server that must share RAM with a database server. Nginx has a tiny footprint and is definitely your best bet. Here is a [wiki page](http://www.wikivs.com/wiki/Apache_vs_nginx) listing some of the performance characteristics of nginx versus Apache. The configuration syntax is very similar to Apache, and you can probably migrate in an evening or two.

This is assuming, of course, that you have a choice of web server...

Comment: Thank you for replying!  I will consider switching to nginx as a last resort.  I'd really like to see what I can do with Apache before I dump it completely, and to that end I still wish to get zts working with MySQL.

Comment: Welp, looks like no one else is interested in posting. I will not deprive you of your answer point. =) Thanks for at least chiming in.