# tuning apache for low ram low traffic server

Tags: apache-2.2, performance-tuning

I have a low end VPS server with 512megs of ram to host downloads of files (~10-25megs each).

what is a good configuration for the following parameters in apache. I expect no more than 10 human users at one time, but will likely have robots eating up resources. My purpose is mostly to limit bad robots (ignoring robots.txt) and bad users so they will not take down the server and cause my account to be suspended.

```
<IfModule prefork.c>
StartServers       8
MinSpareServers    5
MaxSpareServers   20
ServerLimit      256
MaxClients       256
MaxRequestsPerChild  4000
</IfModule>
```

Comment: found the answer here http://serverfault.com/questions/21106/how-to-reduce-memory-usage-on-a-unix-webserver

Comment: You will have trouble fitting more than a few children into 512MB of RAM if you use prefork.  Why are you using that instead of the threaded or event MPMs?  Or nginx?

Comment: @Ladadadada aha. thought of using apache with mod_cban are you saying that's too much? by threaded or event MPMs do you mean "worker"?

Comment: Worker is the correct name.  It uses threads rather than separate processes to serve each request which is why I called it "threaded" but to save on confusion, stick with "worker".  The Event MPM is in addition to prefork and worker. It exists in Apache 2.2 but contains a warning about it being new and unreliable. It is stable in Apache 2.4.  [MPM Documentation here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mpm.html).  [And a question about how to choose the right MPM for you](http://serverfault.com/questions/383526/how-do-i-select-which-apache-mpm-to-use).

Comment: @Ladadadada thnx but will probably not have more than 10 concurrent connections. so prefork should be ok. i'll check the logs to see if i get any memory errors